# Error message when trying to solve 2 coupled PDEs using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I'm currently facing a problem when trying to solve 2 coupled PDEs. I get the warning messages:

**NDSolve::fembdcc: Cross-coupling of dependent variables in DirichletCondition[IPF==IPB/10,z==5.] is not supported in this version.**

**NDSolve::fembdcc: Cross-coupling of dependent variables in DirichletCondition[IPF==IPB/10,z==5.] is not supported in this version.**

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 FirEqn = -D[IPF[z, t], z] - D[IPF[z, t], t]  - IPF[z, t]

 SecEqn = -D[IPB[z, t], z] - D[IPB[z, t], t]  - IPB[z, t]

 solIntEqn = 
      NDSolve[{FirEqn == 0, SecEqn == 0, 
        IPF[0, t] == 4 Exp[-(t - 1)^2], 
        IPB[0, t] == 4 Exp[-(t - 1)^2]/RICP, 
        IPF[5, t] == IPB[5, t]/ROCP}, {IPF, IPB}, {z, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

I know the issue is to do when I specify the boundary condition for z == 5, but that's one of the requirements I need. All help is appreciated! Cheers.

BTW, I'm using version 11.2

Also, ROCP = RICP = 1

Comment: What are RICP and ROCP? It's always good to give all details for the equations as otherwise it's going to be guesswork.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. They are just variables that I’ve set values for.

Comment: Edit you post to include actual values for those variables. Be specific. That will make your question a much better post and you will get upvotes for it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Sorry for not including the values from before, I will be sure to be more thoughtful in the future. Cheers!

Comment: no worries. It's always good to tell new users how to write good posts, then this site can be very useful for you. Happy NDSolve-ing.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad this place is beginner friendly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify initial conditions:

```
FirEqn = -D[IPF[z, t], z] - D[IPF[z, t], t] - IPF[z, t]

SecEqn = -D[IPB[z, t], z] - D[IPB[z, t], t] - IPB[z, t]

(* a wild guess *)
ROCP = 1;
RICP = 1;

solIntEqn = NDSolve[{
   FirEqn == 0, SecEqn == 0,
   IPF[0, t] == 4 Exp[-(t - 1)^2],
   IPF[5, t] == IPB[5, t]/ROCP,
   IPB[0, t] == 4 Exp[-(t - 1)^2]/RICP,
   IPB[z, 0] == 4/(E*RICP),
   IPF[z, 0] == 4/E
   }, {IPF, IPB}, {z, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tested it and it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Ibis_prod1gy, great. Not necessarily in this case, but it is generally a good idea to wait a little before you accept an answer. Not everyone has time immediately to look at post but still might have good ideas for a solution. Thanks for the accept though ;-)

Comment: Ah, I’ll know better for the future. Cheers for the feedback!